# Анимация на сайте HTML

Tags: html

Здравствуйте, начал учить html и хочу узнать на этом языке возможно сделать анимацию на сайте, типа падающих лепестков или снега например? Спасибо....

```js
(function(window) {
 'use strict';

 window.Sakura = (function() {
  var NUM_FLOWER = 25, // 譯懊�譛螟ｧ謨ｰ
   NUM_MAX_SIZE_FLOWER = 3, // 譛螟ｧ繧ｵ繧､繧ｺ縺ｮ譯懈焚

   NUM_KIND_FLOWER = 6, // 譯懊�遞ｮ鬘�
   SIZE_FLOWER = [20, 50, 120], // 譯懊�螟ｧ縺阪＆

   SPRITE_NUM = 7, // 繧ｹ繝励Λ繧､繝医�譫壽焚
   SPRITE_SPEED = 500, // 繧ｹ繝励Λ繧､繝医�騾溘＆(ms)

   FALLING_SPEED = 25000, // 關ｽ荳矩溷ｺｦ��ms��
   FALLING_SPEED_FLUCTUATION = .8; // 關ｽ荳矩溷ｺｦ�域昭繧峨℃��

  var numMaxSizeFlower = NUM_MAX_SIZE_FLOWER;

  function Sakura() {
   this.init();
  }

  Sakura.prototype.init = function() {
   this.createField();
   this.cacheElements();
   this.adjustFeild();
   this.createFlower();
  };

  Sakura.prototype.createField = function() {
   if( document.getElementById('fallFlowerWrap') !== 'null' ) {
    $('#fallFlowerWrap').remove();
   }

   $( document.getElementsByTagName('head') ).append(' <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/sakura.css" /> ');
   $( document.body ).append('<div id="fallFlowerWrap"><div id="fallFlowerField"></div></div>');
  };

  Sakura.prototype.cacheElements = function() {
   this.$wrap = $('#fallFlowerWrap');
   this.$field = $('#fallFlowerField');
  };

  Sakura.prototype.adjustFeild = function() {
   this.winWidth = $(window).width(),
   this.winHeight = $(window).height();

   this.$field.css({
    width: this.winWidth,
    height: this.winHeight
   });
  };

  Sakura.prototype.createFlower = function() {
   var _this = this,
    frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

   for( var i = 0, len = NUM_FLOWER; i < len; ++i ) {
    var $elem = $('<div></div>', {'class': 'sakura'}),
     type = r(NUM_KIND_FLOWER),
     size;

    if( numMaxSizeFlower >= 1 ) {
     size = r(SIZE_FLOWER.length);

     if( size === SIZE_FLOWER.length ) {
      $elem.addClass('blur');
      -- numMaxSizeFlower;
     }
    } else {
     size = r(NUM_MAX_SIZE_FLOWER - 1);
    }

    $elem.css({
     'z-index': size,
     'background-image': 'url(/assets/img/common/flower/sakura' + type + '.png)',
     'width': SIZE_FLOWER[size - 1],
     'height': SIZE_FLOWER[size - 1],
    });

    frag.appendChild( $elem[0] );
   }

   this.$field.append(frag);

   $('.sakura').each(function() {
    _this.initFlower( $(this) );
   });
  };

  Sakura.prototype.initFlower = function($elem) {
   var _this = this,
    options,
    startX = r( this.winWidth ) + (this.winWidth / 3),
    endX = r( startX - 100 );

   options = {
    start: startX,
    end: endX,
    speed: FALLING_SPEED * ( 1 - r(100 - FALLING_SPEED_FLUCTUATION * 100) / 100 ),
    delay: r(FALLING_SPEED / 2),
    size: $elem.css('zIndex')
   }

   switch( options.size ) {
    case 1:
     options.speed *= 1.25;
     break;
    case SIZE_FLOWER.length:
     options.speed *= .5;
     break;
    default:
   }

   _this.fallingFlower($elem, options);
   _this.spriteFlower($elem, options);
  };

  Sakura.prototype.fallingFlower = function($elem, options) {
   var _this = this;

   $elem.velocity({
    // translateX: [ - r(_this.winWidth), 0 ],
    // translateY: [ _this.winHeight, 0 ],
    left: [ options.end, options.start ],
    top: [ _this.winHeight, -200 ],
    rotateZ: [ 10, -10 ]
   }, {
    duration: options.speed,
    delay: options.delay,
    easing: 'easeOutSine',
    complete: function() {
     _this.initFlower( $elem );
    }
   });
  };

  Sakura.prototype.spriteFlower = function($elem, options) {
   var _this = this;

   $elem.velocity({
    backgroundPositionX: [SIZE_FLOWER[options.size - 1] * SPRITE_NUM, 0]
   }, {
    duration: SPRITE_SPEED,
    easing: [ SPRITE_NUM ],
    queue: false,
    complete: function() {
     _this.spriteFlower($elem, options);
    }
   });
  };

  return Sakura;
 }());

 $(function() {
  if( Modernizr.backgroundsize ) {
   $(window).on({
    load: function() {
     initAnimation();
    },
    resize: function() {
     initAnimation();
    }
   })
  }

  function initAnimation() {
   var Sakura = new window.Sakura();
  }
 });
}(this));

// Utility Function
function r(n) {
 return Math.floor( Math.random() * n + 1, 10 );
}
```

Comment: С помощью `css/js`. Вам стоит уточнить вопрос. Пример: https://codepen.io/massiebn/pen/vmkwJ

Comment: Добавте код в [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/773742/edit).

Comment: @Ярослав, с китайскими комментариями :D

Comment: @entithat ну так с японского сайта взято)) не судите строго)

Comment: Я бы попробовал убрать JS и оставить только японский

Comment: @РашенБеар ну а серьезно?)

Comment: @Ярослав на html, без JS, нельзя сделать анимацию

Comment: @РашенБеар спасибо...

Answer (score 0):

анимацию можно реализовать с помощью css или js (или того и того) 
есть даже много готовых библиотек типа [Animate css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) или [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)/[jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/)
Но "типа падающих лепестков или снега" - такое, обычно gif-кой фигачят (вернее фигачили, этак в 2006м)

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать , но снежинок придётся делать очень много (или листьев). Для этого нужен CSS. Анимация создаётся с помощью `@keyframes`. После `@keyframes` указывается имя анимации. Вызывается анимация с помощью свойства `animation`, в котором 
указывается имя анимации, продолжительность и доп. атрибуты.

Пример :

```
.a:hover {
Animation:i 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes{
    100%{color:red;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно, всё зависит от ваших возможностей и фантазии.

Старый пример реализации падающего снег

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.snowContainer {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/WTXMRs4.png') no-repeat center center / cover;
}

#snow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/WajQooJ.png"), url("https://i.imgur.com/svileb8.png"), url("https://i.imgur.com/DQ0wojf.png");
  animation: snow 20s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes snow {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0, 0 0, 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 500px 1000px, 400px 400px, 300px 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="snowContainer">
  <div id="snow"></div>
</div>
```

P.s. за анимацию спасибо сайту Yraaa.